# Pattern in dropping time of Collatz iteration

Tags: collatz-conjecture

I've noticed a linear pattern in the dropping time $C(n)$ of the Collatz iteration ([A122437](https://oeis.org/A122437)) when plotted against the number of digits $d(n)$ in the base-2 representation of $3^n$ ([A020914](https://oeis.org/A020914)).
[image: 1]
Collatz iteration dropping time (vertical) versus the number of digits in the base-2 representation of $3^n$ (horizontal).

For this limited data set the connection can be described by something like
$$C(n)=\lfloor1.635\cdot d(n)\rfloor$$
Is this connection known and if not would it be worth investigating further?
Thanks in advance for sharing your ideas.

Here's how I found the pattern.

Given $n,b\in\mathbb{N}$ let $c(n,b)$ be the dropping time of the set $\{2^n\cdot k+b|k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ if it exists. E.g. $c(1,0)=1$ and $c(4,3)=6$ while $c(3,1)$ is not defined. We don't consider multiples of 2, because $c(3,2)$ is the same as $c(2,1)$, for instance.

From numerical observation it becomes apparent that $\{c(n,b)|b\in\mathbb{N}\wedge(n,b)\in\textrm{dom}(c)\}$ is a singleton, say $\{e(n)\}$. Finally, $e$ only seems to be defined on $\textrm{cod}(d)$ which yields the relation:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:C(n)=e(d(n))$$

Here's the C++ code I did the analysis with.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class residue_class {
 public:
  residue_class(T divisor, T remainder)
      : divisor{divisor},
        remainder{remainder},
        divisor_orig{divisor},
        remainder_orig{remainder} {}

  std::vector<residue_class> solve(std::ostream& stream,
                                   std::map<T, T>& steps_by_divisor) {
    return solve_light(stream, steps_by_divisor)
               ? std::vector<residue_class>{}
               : std::vector<residue_class>{create_even(), create_odd()};
  }

  bool solve_light(std::ostream& stream, std::map<T, T>& steps_by_divisor) {
    while (step()) {
      if (is_smaller()) {
        print(stream);
        auto found{steps_by_divisor.find(divisor_orig)};
        if (found == steps_by_divisor.end()) {
          steps_by_divisor.emplace(divisor_orig, steps);
        } else if (found->second != steps) {
          std::cout << "Found inconsistency in number of steps. Expected "
                    << found->second << ", but found " << steps
                    << " for divisor " << divisor_orig << '\n';
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

 private:
  // a | b | n | a*n+b (mod 2)
  // -----------------
  // 0 | 0 | * | 0
  // 0 | 1 | * | 1
  // 1 | 0 | * | ?
  // 1 | 1 | * | ?
  bool step() {
    bool success{false};
    if (divisor % 2 == 0) {
      if (remainder % 2 == 0) {
        divisor /= 2;
        remainder /= 2;
      } else {
        detect_overflow(3);
        divisor *= 3;
        remainder *= 3;
        ++remainder;
        if (divisor == remainder) {
          remainder = 0;
        }
      }
      ++steps;
      success = true;
    }
    return success;
  }

  bool is_smaller() {
    return divisor < divisor_orig ||
           (divisor == divisor_orig && remainder < remainder_orig);
  }

  residue_class create_even() const {
    residue_class even{*this};
    detect_overflow(2);
    even.divisor *= 2;
    even.divisor_orig *= 2;
    return even;
  }

  residue_class create_odd() const {
    residue_class odd{*this};
    odd.remainder += odd.divisor;
    odd.remainder_orig += odd.divisor_orig;
    detect_overflow(2);
    odd.divisor *= 2;
    odd.divisor_orig *= 2;
    odd.remainder %= odd.divisor;
    odd.remainder_orig %= odd.divisor_orig;
    return odd;
  }

  void print(std::ostream& stream) const {
    stream << divisor_orig << "n+" << remainder_orig << "->" << divisor << "n+"
           << remainder << " in " << steps << "\n";
  }

  void detect_overflow(std::int8_t modulus) const {
    if (divisor >= std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / modulus) {
      std::cout << "Overflow detected: ";
      print(std::cout);
    }
  }

 private:
  T divisor;
  T remainder;
  T steps{0u};
  T divisor_orig;
  T remainder_orig;
};

int main() {
  std::ofstream file{"out.txt"};
  using T = std::int64_t;
  std::map<T, T> steps_by_divisor;
  std::queue<residue_class<T>> todo;
  todo.emplace(2, 0);
  todo.emplace(2, 1);

  std::size_t solved{0u};
  for (auto j{1}; j < 7; ++j) {
    for (auto i{0}; i < std::pow(10, j) && !todo.empty(); ++i) {
      auto modular{std::move(todo.front())};
      todo.pop();
      auto followup{modular.solve(file, steps_by_divisor)};
      if (followup.empty()) {
        ++solved;
      }
      for (auto& task : followup) {
        todo.emplace(std::move(task));
      }
    }
    std::cout << "Summary: " << todo.size() << " unknowns and " << solved
              << " solved with ratio "
              << static_cast<double>(solved) / static_cast<double>(todo.size())
              << '\n';
  }

  std::size_t unknowns{0u};
  while (!todo.empty()) {
    auto modular{std::move(todo.front())};
    todo.pop();
    if (modular.solve_light(file, steps_by_divisor)) {
      ++solved;
    } else {
      ++unknowns;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Summary: " << unknowns << " unknowns and " << solved
            << " solved with ratio "
            << static_cast<double>(solved) / static_cast<double>(unknowns)
            << '\n';

  std::cout << "log2(a)\t#steps\n";
  for (auto const& pair : steps_by_divisor) {
    std::cout << std::log2(pair.first) << "\t" << pair.second << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if related to this, but in the "Formula" section of A122437, we see the following remarks: `a(n) = floor((1+log(2)/log(3))*A020914(n-1)). - K. Spage, Oct 22 2009
a(n) = A020914(n+1)+n-1. - K. Spage, Oct 23 2009`. (A relation equivalent to the second remark is also present in A020914) This shows that a connection between the two sequences is known.

Comment: That settles it then and reminds me to pay attention to all the text for a sequence on the OEIS. Thank you very much and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Not much to investigate: $d(n)=\lceil n\log_2(3)\rceil$ and $C(n)=d(n)+n$, so you end up with $C(n)=\lfloor d(n) \log_3(6) \rfloor$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly to get this out of the unanswered queue but this should be fairly simple to show:

$$r\bmod 2= 2^nx+r\bmod 2$$ so until all the factors of 2 are gone, the two have the same pattern in dropping. The residues $r$ that survive $n=11$ without dropping below their starting points are:

$$27, 31, 47, 63, 71, 91, 103, 111, 127, 155, 159, 167, 191, 207, 223, 231, 239, 251, 255, 283, 303, 319, 327, 359, 383, 411, 415, 447, 463, 479, 487, 495, 511, 539, 543, 559, 603, 615, 623, 639, 667, 671, 679, 703, 719, 743, 751, 763, 767, 795, 799, 831, 839, 859, 871, 879, 895, 927, 935, 959, 991, 1007, 1019, 1023, 1051, 1055, 1071, 1087, 1095, 1115, 1127, 1135, 1151, 1179, 1183, 1191, 1215, 1231, 1247, 1255, 1263, 1275, 1279, 1307, 1327, 1343, 1351, 1383, 1407, 1435, 1439, 1471, 1487, 1503, 1511, 1519, 1535, 1563, 1567, 1583, 1627, 1639, 1647, 1663, 1691, 1695, 1703, 1727, 1743, 1767, 1775, 1787, 1791, 1819, 1823, 1855, 1863, 1883, 1895, 1903, 1919, 1951, 1959, 1983, 2015, 2031, 2043, 2047$$

These are the only residues that could be minimal escapes or minimum in a loop.